# Error in Table creation through PDO

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

try{
  $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname"; // $dbname is empdb as in dbconfig.php
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

 $sql_create_dept_tbl = <<<EOSQL
 CREATE TABLE departments(
 department_no int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (department_no)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB
 EOSQL;

 $sql_create_emp_tbl = <<<EOSQL
 CREATE TABLE employees (
 employee_no int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 first_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 last_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 department_no int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (employee_no),
 KEY emp_dept (department_no),
 CONSTRAINT emp_dept FOREIGN KEY (department_no)
 REFERENCES departments (department_no)
 )  ENGINE=InnoDB
 EOSQL;

$msg = '';

$r = $dbh->exec($sql_create_dept_tbl);

 if($r !== false){
   $r = $dbh->exec($sql_create_emp_tbl);

if($r !== false){
  $msg =  "Tables are created successfully!<br/>";
}else{
  $msg =  "Error creating the employees table.<br/>";
}

}else{
  $msg =  "Error creating the departments table.<br/>";
}

// display the message
if($msg != '')
  echo $msg;
}catch (PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I have gone through all the initialization still all I get is

**"Error creating the departments table."**

But I see a "departments" table already created in the database (empdb).
Why am I getting an error message when the table is already created?? . I am using WAMP server and phpMyadmin to access the database.
Any help regarding this will be of utmost value to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) to your table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departments(
 department_no int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (department_no)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because your table is already created and can`t be created again, so:

```
$r = $dbh->exec($sql_create_dept_tbl) // result is false
```

so below chunk of code getting printed

```
}else{
$msg =  "Error creating the departments table.<br/>";
}
```

you can check if table already exists and run creation or skip it:

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT 1 FROM $table_name LIMIT 1");
if($result){
    //// skip table creation
} else {
    //// run table creation script
    $r = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a table with same name more than once . It's always a good practice to check whether the table already exist or not . Use this it will help you ,

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] table name
```